# In SQL, can I get the values in one column that don't have a certain value associated to them in another column?

Tags: mysql, sql, exists

Let's say I have a table with two columns: user_guid and trait.
The same user_guid can appear multiple times in the table with different traits in the second column.
Like this:

```
-----------------------
user_guid | trait
-----------------------
a123      | tall
a123      | sings
a123      | blonde
b321      | short
b321      | sings
```

Is there a way to get all the user_guids that don't have the value 'tall' in the trait column?
I am trying to use WHERE NOT EXISTS, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is aggregation:

```
select user_guid
from t
group by user_guid
having sum(trait = 'tall') = 0;
```

Note:  This will not return users with no traits at all.  For that, you need a separate table of users:

```
select u.*
from users u
where not exists (select 1
                  from t
                  where t.user_guid = u.user_uid and t.trait = 'tall'
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery in `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.user_guid
FROM yourTable AS t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable AS t2
     WHERE t2.user_guid = t1.user_guid AND t2.trait = 'tall')
```

or you can use a self-join

```
SELECT DISTING t1.user_guid
FROM yourTable AS t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable AS t2 ON t1.user_guid = t2.user_guid AND t2.trait = 'tall'
WHERE t2.user_guid IS NULL
```